# Revised Ranger Animal Companion Damage

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger

One of my players has an Ape companion with the Revised Ranger. Do you add the Ape's Strength modifier of +3 to damage rolls as well as the ranger's proficiency bonus?

Answer (score 20):

### Yes

The relevant passage does not say that you use the proficiency bonus *instead* of some modifier. Instead, it specifies that you *add* it:

> In addition to the areas where it normally uses its proficiency bonus, an animal    companion also adds    its proficiency bonus to    its 
>   AC  and to  its damage  rolls.

The Ape's entry in the MM has a +3 to its damage rolls (probably from its strength, like you say), and the feature does not eliminate that bonus, meaning that it gains +3+(proficiency) to its damage rolls.